# How to return blank or zero when 'On Error Resume Next' leaves previous value in variable?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have VBA code that gets the stock price in a loop.

There are stock symbols not found in this API source. It will result to error for those stocks.

I'm using `On Error Resume Next` so the VBA code will continue to the next symbol.

My problem is the symbol in error will return a stock price of the last stock symbol not in error.

I would like to make the result blank or zero for the stock symbols in error.

Current Result - the *italicized symbols* are those that are in error.

**Stock Symbol** **Price**
BDO 158.00
ABS 15.80
GREEN 1.87
*ALHI* *1.87*
*LAND* *1.87*
PLC 0.57
*LBC* *0.57*
*EVER* *0.57*

Desired Result - the *italicized symbols* those that are in error will result or will give return of 0

**Stock Symbol** **Price**
BDO 158.00
ABS 15.80
GREEN 1.87
*ALHI* *0*
*LAND* *0*
PLC 0.57
*LBC* *0*
*EVER* *0*

```
    Set myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    myrequest.Open "Get", "http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/" & symbol & ".json"
    myrequest.Send

    Dim Json As Object
    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)

    i = Json("stock")(1)("price")("amount")
    ws.Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 2)) = i

    n = n + 1

    On Error Resume Next

Next X

ws.Columns("B").AutoFit
MsgBox ("Stock Quotes Refreshed.")

ws.Range("B4:B" & lastrow).HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
ws.Range("B4:B" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, the Stock Symbol and Price is in different columns.

Comment: Can you add the JSON response in the question for valid and invalid stocks ?

Comment: [Format data as table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) and have a look at [VBA-Web](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web) for webrequest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always put a conditional check statement based on the error you receive for invalid stocks, if you are getting empty value in `myrequest` on invalid stock. You can write your logic like below and update price value to 0.

```vb
If myrequest is Nothing Then
    'For Invalid Stocks
End
```

or

```vb
If myrequest.ResponseText = "" Then
    'For Invalid Stocks
End
```

Let me know if it helps. Otherwise share the JSON response for both valid and invalid stocks.

**Update:**
Based on the value of `myrequest.ResponseStatus` for invalid response, update the `<add-condition>` condition in `If` statement according to your requirement.

```vb
For Each X In rng

    Dim Json As Object
    Dim i
    symbol = X

    Set myrequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    myrequest.Open "Get", "http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/" & symbol & ".json"
    On Error Resume Next
    myrequest.Send
    On Error GoTo 0

    Debug.Print myrequest.ResponseStatus

    If <add-condition> Then
        Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(myrequest.ResponseText)
        i = Json("stock")(1)("price")("amount")
    Else
        i = 0
    End If

    ws.Range(Cells(n, 2), Cells(n, 2)) = i
    n = n + 1

Next X
```

Comment: Hi @stud3nt. Normally the code will stop if I remove the onerror resume next.

Comment: Maybe you are getting error due to some other statement. Please remove the on resume statement and tell us what error are you getting and where ? Because `On Error Resume Next` statement will only work for errors occurring after it.

Comment: if I remove the OERN, this is the error I'm getting Run-time error '10001': Error Parsing JSON: Expecting '{' or '['

Comment: Normally, this would be the JSON result, I'm only getting the amount. But if the symbol is invalid the page will result to page can't be found HTTP error 404.  {"stock":[{"name":"Banco de Oro","price":{"currency":"PHP","amount":158.00},"percent_change":0.38,"volume":2245820,"symbol":"BDO"}],"as_of":"2019-12-27T15:20:00+08:00"}

Comment: This is the webpage result if the symbol is not found. This phisix-api3.appspot.com page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://phisix-api3.appspot.com/stocks/ALHI.json
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: Please check I have updated the answer. Also, you have to debug the code to find out the value of response on invalid request and add that as your condition for updating price in your excel.

Comment: The JSON response would be this. The invalid symbols will just be blank. How I should put this in the IF statement. Example here, there are two blank lines between GREEN and PLC symbol (valid symbols). In between are the invalid symbols ALHI and LAND.

{"stock":[{"name":"GREEN","price":{"currency":"PHP","amount":1.87},"percent_change":-0.53,"volume":9898000,"symbol":"GREEN"}],"as_of":"2019-12-27T15:20:00+08:00"}


{"stock":[{"name":"PREMIUM LEISURE","price":{"currency":"PHP","amount":0.57},"percent_change":0.00,"volume":14396000,"symbol":"PLC"}],"as_of":"2019-12-27T15:20:00+08:00"}

Comment: Valid is fine. Try to capture the invalid one condition. For example: `If ResponseCode <> "404"` perform json parse otherwise set to 0. It is difficult for me to write code without access to the api. Hope this will help

Comment: Hi @stud3nt. I made some update on the your suggested answer. And now it works.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I will upvote and mark it as answered.

Comment: You can read this guide on [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) and [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Also, remove the comments which have code.

Comment: @stud3nt I edited to add the necessary error reset.  Hope you don't mind

Answer (score 3):

Your code as it stands sets `On Error Resume Next` at the end of the first time through the loop, and from that point on ignores any and all errors. That's bad.

The general method of using OERN should be

```
Other non error causing code
Optionally initialise variables in preparation for error trap
On Error Resume Next
   Execute the instruction that might cause an error
On Error GoTo 0
If (test if instruction succeeded) Then
    Process the result
Else 
    Optionally handle the error case
End If
```

Comment: Hi @chris neilsen, appreciate your suggestion but I'm no expert on VBA, so I'm not sure how to apply the suggested method. Thanks.

Comment: @StockTracker read https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/11022/resume-keyword!