# Outlook mail intermittently not sent using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have an intermittent Excel VBA problem when sending via Outlook.

20 or 30 times a day my clients send email files. About once a week the email doesn't send.  It's not in the Outbox or Sent. We only find out when we receive a physical sample without the corresponding email, usually the next day.

The relevant Excel VBA code:

```vb
'[bunch of code that sets everything up in order to send]    

Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set OutMail = oOutlook.CreateItem(0) ' [oOutlook is a previously created object which is an instance of Outlook]
With OutMail
    .To = Address ' [Address=email I have pre-filled]
    .Subject = "Swabs File"
    .body = vbAns ' [vbAns = variant I have pre-filled]
    .Attachments.Add (Dir) ' [Dir = string which is the name of the file]
    .send
End With

'Error trap if there is any problem at all
If Err Then
    MsgBox ("Problem with Outlook - Failed to Send. Please try again")
    Exit Sub
else
    MsgBox ("Your file has been sent")
End If
```

When the problem occurs the error isn't trapped, and the client thinks they have successfully sent the file.

How can I trap the error?

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub test()

    Dim oOutlook As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    
    ' *** with Outlook ***
    ' As many times as you want there will only be one
    'Set oOutlook = New outlook.Application
    
    'On Error Resume Next   ' generate mysterious failure,
    '                          hide error so developer cannot debug
    
    On Error GoTo trap      ' Error trap if there is any problem at all
    
    If Not oOutlook Is Nothing Then ' confirm Outlook is available
    
        Set OutMail = oOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        
        With OutMail
        
            '.To = Address ' [Address=email I have pre-filled]
            .Subject = "Swabs File"
            '.body = vbAns ' [vbAns = variant I have pre-filled]
            
            Error 5   ' for demonstration
            .Attachments.Add (dir) ' [Dir = string which is the name of the file]
            
            .Display    '.Send
            
        End With
        
        MsgBox "Your file has been sent"
        
    Else
    
        MsgBox "oOutlook object does not exist - Failed to Send."
        
    End If
    
    Exit Sub    ' <---  bypass the trap if no error
    

trap:   'Error trap if there is any problem at all
    
    MsgBox "Problem with Outlook - Failed to Send. Please try again"

End Sub
```

Only use `On Error Resume Next` when "[You **know** why the error occurs.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31753321/1571407)"
You can either take steps to address the error or ignore it on purpose.

[There is a general method of using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550602/1571407) `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Thanks for your help niton - I ended up removing all error detection completely, so that the code would fall over when there was a problem - it didn't. 
The email sent umpteen times, then failed once, but there was no error message.
I think what I'm going to have to do, is to go into the "Sent" box on outlook and see if my email is there - if it is then good, else please try again.
Going forward I will use your error trapping method for other code.
Thanks again.