# Save weekly email attachments in an Outlook folder to hard drive

Tags: vba, outlook

I coded a macro that will save the attachments in an Outlook folder (Style Transfers) to a folder on my hard drive (desktop).

It will save all the attachments located in the Outlook folder. I need to save only current week email attachments.

```vb
Option Explicit
Const folderPath = "C:\Users\dilshanra\Desktop\Style Transfers\"

Sub Saveattachments()
On Error Resume Next
Dim ns As NameSpace
Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim searchFolder As String
searchFolder = InputBox("What is your subfolder name?")

Dim subFolder As MAPIFolder

Dim Item As Object
Dim Attach As Attachment
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer

If searchFolder <> "inbox" Then
    Set subFolder = Inbox.Folders(searchFolder)
    i = 0
    If subFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
          "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For Each Item In subFolder.Items
        For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
            Attach.SaveAsFile (folderPath & Attach.FileName)
            i = i + 1
        Next Attach
    Next Item

Else
    i = 0
    If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Inbox.", vbInformation, _
          "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Item In Inbox.Items
        For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
            FileName = folderPath & Attach.FileName
            Attach.SaveAsFile FileName
            i = i + 1
        Next Attach
    Next Item
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Incorporate an  `If DateDiff("d", Item.SentOn, Now) <= 7 Then` catch into the function

Comment: @Tragamor Hi, Where should I insert the IF condition? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in a folder is not really a good idea:

```
For Each Item In subFolder.Items
  For Each Attach In Item.Attachments
```

Instead, you need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the `Items` class to find items that correspond to your search criteria. Here are the steps required to get the job done correctly:

---

First, you need to modify the search condition to get mail items for a specific time frame.

```
DateToCheck = "[RecievedTime] >= """ & DateStart & """"
```

Feel free to expand the search criteria according to your needs.

---

Second, you need to iterate over all items found in the loop, not just get the first and process attachments (VBA syntax):

```
Set myRestrictItems = myContacts.Restrict(DateToCheck)  
For Each myItem In myRestrictItems  
    If (myItem.Class = olMail) Then  
       MsgBox myItem.Subject & ": " & myItem.RecievedTime
    End If  
Next
```

The [MailItem.ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime) property returns a `Date` indicating the date and time at which the item was received.

---

Third, here is the search query for items with attachments (VBA syntax):

```
query ="@SQL=" & chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & chr(34) & "=True"
```

or

```
query ="@SQL=" & chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & chr(34) & "=1"
```

---

You can read more about [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Retrieve Outlook calendar items using Find and FindNext methods](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/11/outlook-retrieve-calendar-items/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method in Outlook to get calendar items](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/15/outlook-restrict-calendar-items/)

Answer (score 0):

Misuse of `On Error Resume Next` = Do not allow debugging.

[VBA: How long does On Error Resume Next work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31753201/vba-how-long-does-on-error-resume-next-work/31753321#31753321)

[How to return blank or zero when 'On Error Resume Next' leaves previous value in variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59550283/how-to-return-blank-or-zero-when-on-error-resume-next-leaves-previous-value-in/59550602#59550602)

```vb
Option Explicit

Const folderPath = "C:\Users\dilshanra\Desktop\Style Transfers\"

Sub Saveattachments()

Dim Inbox As Folder
Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

Dim inputBoxMsg As String
inputBoxMsg = "What is your folder name (not case-sensitive)?" & vbCr & vbCr & _
  "Inbox or folder one level below Inbox."

Dim searchFolder As String
searchFolder = InputBox(inputBoxMsg, , "Inbox")

Dim myFolder As Folder

Dim Item As Object
Dim Attach As Attachment
Dim FileName As String

If LCase(searchFolder) <> LCase("Inbox") Then

    ' Bypass expected error when the folder cannot be found.
    On Error Resume Next
    Set myFolder = Inbox.Folders(searchFolder)
    ' Limit error bypass to the least number of lines possible.
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If myFolder Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Folder not found under Inbox: " & searchFolder
        MsgBox "Folder not found under Inbox: " & searchFolder
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    saveFromFolder myFolder
    
Else
    Set myFolder = Inbox
    saveFromFolder myFolder
    
End If

End Sub


Private Sub saveFromFolder(myFolder As Folder)

    Dim fldrItems As Items
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    
    Dim myItem As Object
    Dim Attach As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    
    Dim userErrMsg As String
    
    ' Could ".Restrict" to the applicable recent mailitems with attachments.
    
    ' This less efficient approach should be fast enough in this case,
    '  if the folder has a "reasonable" number of recently received items.
    
    'Sort collection of items newest to oldest. Exit when the first older mail is found.
    Set fldrItems = myFolder.Items
    fldrItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", True

    i = 0
    j = 0
    
    For Each myItem In fldrItems
    
        'Ensure item is a mailitem before attempting to return mailitem properties
        If TypeOf myItem Is MailItem Then
            
            ' ReceivedTime is usually a better match for incoming mail
            Debug.Print DateDiff("d", myItem.ReceivedTime, Now) & " days old. ", myItem.ReceivedTime
            If DateDiff("d", myItem.ReceivedTime, Now) <= 7 Then
    
                Debug.Print myItem.ReceivedTime, myItem.Subject
                For Each Attach In myItem.Attachments
                
                    i = i + 1
                    
                    'Bypass expected error when the attachment cannot be saved.
                    'Test with a valid example without On Error Resume Next
                    ' to not bypass an unexpected error, for example a syntax error.
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Attach.SaveAsFile (folderPath & Attach.FileName)
                    
                    Debug.Print " FileName: " & Attach.FileName
                    
                    If err <> 0 Then
                        userErrMsg = "  Error attempting to save attachment to " & folderPath
                        userErrMsg = userErrMsg & vbCr & "   " & err.Number & vbTab & err.Description
                        
                        Debug.Print userErrMsg
                        'MsgBox userErrMsg
                        
                        i = i - 1
                        j = j + 1
                    End If
                    
                    'Limit error bypass to the least number of lines possible.
                    'The debugger will advise you of subsequent unexpected errors
                    . so you can fix them.
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    
                Next Attach
                
            Else
                
                ' Exit to not process all items in the folder
                Debug.Print myItem.ReceivedTime, myItem.Subject
                Debug.Print " Exiting on old mail."
                Exit For
                    
            End If
        End If
        
    Next myItem
    
    userErrMsg = i & " attachments saved."
    userErrMsg = userErrMsg & vbCr & j & " errors / attachments not saved."
    Debug.Print userErrMsg
    MsgBox userErrMsg
    
End Sub
```