Loop to move emails based on date skips some emails
I've written some VBA code to move emails from one folder to another in Outlook based on a set of date ranges. It counts correctly, but only moves a few of the emails that it should.
Sub MoveEmails()
    Dim SourceNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim SourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim TargetNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim TargetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim EmailCount As Long
    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    
    ' Confirm with the user before proceeding
    Response = MsgBox("This might take a while. Would you like to proceed?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation")
    If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Set reference to the source and target folders
    Set SourceNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set SourceFolder = SourceNamespace.PickFolder ' Select the source folder
    Set TargetNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set TargetFolder = TargetNamespace.PickFolder ' Select the target folder
    
    ' Show the source and target folders to the user
    MsgBox "Source Folder: " & SourceFolder.FolderPath & vbCrLf & "Target Folder: " & TargetFolder.FolderPath, vbInformation, "Folders Selected"
    
    ' Get the date range from the user
    StartDate = InputBox("Enter the start date (dd/mm/yyyy):")
    EndDate = InputBox("Enter the end date (dd/mm/yyyy):")
    
    ' Show the progress form
    frmProgress.Show vbModeless
    
    ' Call the recursive function to move emails and get the count of emails moved
    EmailCount = MoveFolderEmails(SourceFolder, TargetFolder, StartDate, EndDate)
    
    ' Hide the progress form
    Unload frmProgress
    
    ' Show a summary of the number of emails moved to the user
    MsgBox EmailCount & " emails have been moved.", vbInformation, "Operation Completed"
    
    ' Clean up
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set SourceNamespace = Nothing
    Set TargetFolder = Nothing
    Set TargetNamespace = Nothing
End Sub

The function
Function MoveFolderEmails(SourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, TargetFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder, StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date) As Long
    Dim SourceItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Filter As String
    Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim TargetSubfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim EmailCount As Long
    
    ' Set the date range for emails to be moved
    Filter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(StartDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(EndDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & "'"
    
    ' Get the collection of items in the source folder that meet the criteria
    Set SourceItems = SourceFolder.Items.Restrict(Filter)
    
     ' Loop through each item in the collection and move it to the target folder
     For Each Item In SourceItems
        
        If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
            Item.Move TargetFolder
            
            ' Increment the count of emails moved and update the counter on screen
            
            EmailCount = EmailCount + 1
            frmProgress.lblCount.Caption = "Number of emails moved: " & EmailCount
            
            DoEvents ' Yield to other processes
            
        End If
        
        If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then DoEvents ' Yield to other processes
        
    Next Item
    
    ' Loop through each subfolder in the source folder
    For Each Subfolder In SourceFolder.Folders
        On Error Resume Next
        Set TargetSubfolder = TargetFolder.Folders(Subfolder.Name)
        
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Set TargetSubfolder = TargetFolder.Folders.Add(Subfolder.Name)
            Err.Clear
        End If
       
       EmailCount = EmailCount + MoveFolderEmails(Subfolder, TargetSubfolder, StartDate, EndDate)
       
       Set TargetSubfolder = Nothing
       
       On Error GoTo 0
       
    Next Subfolder
    
    MoveFolderEmails = EmailCount
    
End Function

I was expecting that it would move all the emails rather than what seems a random subset. I suspect that the amount needs to be chunked somehow for Outlook to be able to process.

This question is similar to: For Each loop: Some items get skipped when looping through Outlook mailbox to delete items. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Your error bypass code appears to be inefficient/risky. Consider this folder test where the error bypass is removed immediately. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70972623/1571407

Thanks will follow up in the next couple of days and edit accordingly--your help is appreciated!

Do not edit the question with working code. If you wish to share a solution post an answer.

Yeah sorry I meant update the status and if the questions you posted already answer/sort out my problem.

The main fix is to move items (or delete) in reverse order.
Additionally non-US date format dd/mm/yyyy changes to mm/dd/yyyy when dd is less than 13.
Option Explicit


Sub MoveEmails()

    Dim sourceFolder As folder
    Dim targetFolder As folder
    Dim emailCount As Long
    
    Dim startDate As Date
    Dim endDate As Date
    Dim strFilter As String
    
    Dim strMsg As String
    
    ' Confirm with the user before proceeding
    strMsg = "This might take a while. Would you like to proceed?"
    If MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Set reference to the source and target folders
    Set sourceFolder = Session.PickFolder ' Select the source folder
    If sourceFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set targetFolder = Session.PickFolder ' Select the target folder
    If targetFolder Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Show the source and target folders to the user
    strMsg = "Source Folder: " & sourceFolder.folderPath & vbCrLf & "Target Folder: " & targetFolder.folderPath
    If MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Confirmation") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Get the date range from the user
    ' If not yyyy-mm-dd, test with a day less than 13 to ensure day and month are not switched
    'startDate = InputBox("Enter the start date (dd/mm/yyyy):")
    'endDate = InputBox("Enter the end date (dd/mm/yyyy):")
    
    'startDate = InputBox("Enter the start date (yyyy-mm-dd):")
    startDate = InputBox("Enter the start date (yyyy-mm-dd):", , Format(Date - 367, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
    Debug.Print Format(startDate, "DDDDD HH:NN")
    
    'endDate = InputBox("Enter the end date (yyyy-mm-dd):")
    endDate = InputBox("Enter the end date (yyyy-mm-dd):", , Format(Date, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
    Debug.Print Format(endDate, "DDDDD HH:NN")
        
    endDate = endDate + 1
    Debug.Print Format(endDate, "DDDDD HH:NN") ' beginning of next day
    
    ' Set the date range for emails to be moved
    strFilter = "[ReceivedTime] >= '" & Format(startDate, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "' And [ReceivedTime] <= '" & Format(endDate, "DDDDD HH:NN") & "'"
    Debug.Print strFilter
    
    ' Call the recursive function to move emails and get the count of emails moved
    emailCount = moveFolderEmails(sourceFolder, targetFolder, strFilter)
    
    ' Show a summary of the number of emails moved to the user
    MsgBox emailCount & " emails have been moved.", vbInformation, "Operation Completed"
    
    ' Clean up can be useful when code called from, for example, Excel
    
End Sub


Function moveFolderEmails(sourceFolder As folder, targetFolder As folder, strFilter As String) As Long

    Dim sourceItems As Items
    
    Dim subfolder As folder
    Dim targetSubfolder As folder
    
    Dim emailCount As Long
    
    ' Get the collection of items in the source folder that meet the criteria
    Set sourceItems = sourceFolder.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
    Debug.Print sourceFolder.Name
    
    ' Loop through each item in the collection and move it to the target folder
    ' Loop in reverse when changing the number of items in a collection
    '  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068
    Dim i As Long
    For i = sourceItems.count To 1 Step -1
     
        If TypeOf sourceItems(i) Is MailItem Then
        
            sourceItems(i).Move targetFolder
            
            ' Increment the count of emails moved and update the counter
            emailCount = emailCount + 1
            Debug.Print "Number of emails moved: " & emailCount
            
            DoEvents    ' Yield to other processes
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    ' Loop through each subfolder in the source folder
    For Each subfolder In sourceFolder.Folders
    
        On Error Resume Next
        Set targetSubfolder = targetFolder.Folders(subfolder.Name)
        ' Minimum error bypass
        On Error GoTo 0
        
        If targetSubfolder Is Nothing Then
            Set targetSubfolder = targetFolder.Folders.Add(subfolder.Name)
        End If
        
        emailCount = emailCount + moveFolderEmails(subfolder, targetSubfolder, strFilter)
        
        Set targetSubfolder = Nothing
        
    Next subfolder
    
    moveFolderEmails = emailCount
    
End Function

